# Nice way to handle EMR cluster limit

Tags: shell, emr

I am using EMR to process logs. So basically it's a command line tool that fires up some clusters and then set up the processing part. The problem I am facing is that when multiple people simultaneously try to use the tool. It tries to fire up a cluster for each of them thereby reaching the MAX_LIMIT of 50. I cannot create and leave a cluster forever running as it can be idle and will incur a cost.

How do I handle this part inside the script. Also how can I set up a priority in killing up the EMR cluster and setting up a new onw for a high priority request.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no amazon provided tools for that.

You can either run a persistent cluster and terminate it with a script if it's idle for some time, and restart the claster on request. Sure it requires some monitoring tool running on background. Or you can implement a task queue, and ensure at most one task is run at a given moment.

But all the options you have to implement yourself, though it seems to be pretty straightforward and relatively easy to do with any scripting language. We have something similar to the second option written on python, and running as a service on a dedicated machine.